# If $Ax = b$ has more than one solution so does $Ax = 0$, where $A$ is $m\times n$ real matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Problem:**  If $Ax = b$ has more than one solution so does $Ax = 0$, where $A$ is $m\times n$ real matrix.

In the explanation part it is written that when $Ax = b$ is consistent the solution sets of non-homogeneous equation and the homogeneous equation are translates of each other. So, in
this case, the two equations have the same number of solutions.

I am not able to understand what exactly above explanation says?

However, I was thinking that if $Ax = b$ has more than one solution then it must be infinite. Hence there must be at least one free variable. Thus corresponding homogeneous system must be having infinite solutions. Am I thinking correctly?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The point is that, if $Ax=0$ has a solution, since the solution set is a linear subspace, it should contain the line spanned by that solution and so infinite if the ground field is infinite.

Comment: I didn't read your question. Consider two distinct solutions $u,v$ of $Ax=b$. it holds that $A(u-v)=Au-Av=b-b$. This gives you a non-null solution to $Ax=\bf 0$.

Comment: @GitGud Thank you I understood now. I also want to know whether my explanation is correct?

Comment: @FrankScience Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too many words here, this is quite simple:

if $Ax = b = Ax_1$, then $A\times 0 = 0 = A(x-x_1)$. If $x\neq x_1$ then there are (at least) two different solutions to $Ax = 0$: $0$ and $x-x_1$ (and by the way, for any scalar $\lambda$, $\lambda(x-x_1)$ is also a solution).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please tell me whether my explanation is correct or not?

Comment: your explanation seems correct but not that precise (blabla is less precise than simple equation ;)).

Comment: :) Got it. Thanks a ton.

Comment: thnaks :) {} {} {}

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ and $y$ be two solutions of $Ax = b$, with $x\not= y$. Then: $$A(x-y) =Ax - Ay = b - b = 0$$so $x-y$ is a non-trivial solution of $Ax = 0$, and $\lambda(x-y)$ is a solution for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ so there are infinitely many.