# If  =  has exactly one solution then  = 0 also has exactly one solution

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't find the proof of this statement. Could someone help me ?

Comment: Hint: Suppose that $x_0$ is a solution to $Ax=0$ and $x_1$ is a solution to $Ax=b$. What can you say about $x_0+x_1$ ?

Comment: $b= 0$ is just a particular case.

Comment: See also [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849390/if-ax-b-has-more-than-one-solution-so-does-ax-0-where-a-is-m-times-n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is the unique solution to $Ax=b$, then
$$Ay=0=b-b=Ax-b=A(x-A^{-1}b).$$ You require the dimensions of $x,b,A$ to be consistent for the matrix multiplications and $A$ non-singular though. We can then choose $y= x-A^{-1}b$ and this is unique if $A^{-1}$ is an injective map, which is necessarily true if it is non-singular. In general, $Ax=b$ is just the affine plane obtained by shifting $Ax=0$ and clearly a translation is bijective and so one having a unique solution leads to the other.

Comment: $A$ may not be regular ...

Comment: This assumes $A$ is non-singular. Of course then $Ax = 0$ has just a single solution and $Ax = b$ also has just a single solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the set of solutions of $Ax=b$ is an affine subspace of $K^n$ ($K$ being the base field, and $n$ the dimension of the square matrix $A$), with directing subspace $\ker A$.